# How to use LeScanCallback when trying to find BLE-devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an application in Android and I want it to find and list BLE-devices.

There aren't very many topics on it here and I don't get it. I've tried to use the

```
startLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback);
```

But Eclipse says that LeScanCallback can't be resolved or is not a field (I have the same problem with BluetoothManager and LeDeviceListAdapter). I have all the BT permissions, imported BluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattCallback and have the Samsung SDk jar-file in the right place. What have I missed?

I've used this codesuggestion from the Android developers page (only a part of my code), but I can't get it to work:

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {

// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
public boolean scanning;
public BluetoothAdapter aBTAdapter;
public Handler aHandler;

//------------------------------------------------

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        aHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scanning = false;
                aBTAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        scanning = true;

        aBTAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

    } else {
        scanning = false;
        aBTAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
};
//------------------------------------------
```

}

What do I have to do for Eclipse to recognize BluetoothManager, LeDeviceListAdapter and LeScanCallback?
How do I introduce the mLeScanCallback-variable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm sort of new to programming so pedagogical answers please.

---

Edit:

I have tried this code to declare the callback but it doesn't work, gives me the same error as mentioned above (BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback can't be resolved or is not a field):

```
private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
            byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
               mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });
   }
};
```

Also, errors --> can't run it --> no log

Comment: Which Android API version you are using??

Answer (score 2):

The Bluetooth SIG has a application accelerator kit for BLE which includes complete working code for Android.  Great resource to get started, free download at https://developer.bluetooth.org/Pages/Bluetooth-Smart-Developers.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, briefly, and resolved it by:

First make sure you have API level 18+ downloaded.  Right click on your project, go to Properties -> Android.  Make sure Android 4.3 or above is selected as the Project Build Target.  Apply the changes, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There's even a code sample below the one you used:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#find

You need to introduce a field variable like this:

```
// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
            byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
               mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });
   }
};
```

Comment: I have tried that but I get the same error there. Eclipse doesn't recognize BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the same ( / similar) problem..
In my case I miss-added **another android.jar** (api 4) in addition to the *Reference Library*. Eclipse was using the added one so the `LeScanCallback` interface wasn't existing (in my case `Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE` wasn't nether..)

I had to remove the unexpected jar :

1. In eclipse package explorer, right click on the project
2. *Build Path* > *Configure build path*
3. Go to *Librairies* tab
4. Select the bad android.jar
5. delete

Best regards,

Léni

Answer (score 0):

You can try Shift+ Crtl + O, to organize imports. If you use API 18, then it should automatically add appropriate imports;
**import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;**

If not -  make sure you have API 18 installed in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: I've tried to import but it doesn't work and the API 18 is installed.

Answer (score -1):

Well I think you have to first understand a few concept before working on.

1.Understand what is a class, what is an object, what is a variable, even better to understand variable scope, etc.

If the code you post is the full code it is definitely not working, as you just copy some a part of code without declaring the variable the code uses. For example, you have to declare and init mLeScanCallback like Boni2k does before using the variable.

2.Do not mix up Samsung BLE SDK and the Android BLE code. They are similar, but what you are doing have nothing to do with Samsung BLE SDK,so including the Samsung JAR definitely not helping the situation.

Although BLE development in Android is not hard by means of code complexity (high level remote IO API !), I think you will suffer if you dig into it with no programming foundation. Better go through some basic Java programming (at least to understand the example code) and Android development concepts.

Comment: The included code is just a part of my code and I tried the example code provided by Boni2k without success.

Comment: @emmjon have you import the class?

Comment: which class do you mean? I've tried 'import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;' but that just gives me an error. Same with LeScanCallback and LeDeviceListAdapter. Is there an other way to import?

Comment: @emmjon Please post the full error log so it is better for others to understand the actual problem. Without the log my guess is that there is problem in the project settings.

Comment: Since there are errors in the code I can't run it --> no log. Yes, there is something wrong with the settings/imports since Eclipse doesn't recognize the functions. The question is what?